# Reports with dynamic fitering criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a requirement where a user will be choosing the three filter criteria for reports. These criteria can be any field of a table. User will be once defining it for a department and it may be different for other departments.

Now the challenge is to build up a query with these dynamic criteria. Is there anyway other than dynamic query to achive this? If dynamic query is the only possible solution, how can I minimise the SQL injections.

I'd appreciate any help.

### EDIT

I'm actually looking for a way where I can fetch the fields set up as fitering criteria and its value. We're using SPs.

Now should I pass column name and its value or is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
AND (@variable1 = '-1' OR column = @variable1)
AND (@variable2 = '-1' OR column = @variable2)
AND (@variable3 = '-1' OR column = @variable3)
```

Here is an alternative have a try

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> These criteria can be any field of a table. User will be once defining it for a department and it may be different for other departments.

First of all, there are many different ways of accessing your database. How do you read/write your data?

- ADO.Net
- NHibernate
- Entity-Framework
- other?

As for myself, I only know NHibernate well. In that case I would create a so called query-class with the needed filters as properties. The class itself internally would create HQL (or ICriteria), using parameters in order to avoid any injection.
Or there is also the possibility of creating a stored procedure, taking filters as arguments and returning a view.

Or am I completely missing the point here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE
      (Col1 = @Col1Value OR @Col1Value IS NULL)
  AND (Col2 = @Col2Value OR @Col2Value IS NULL)
  AND (Col3 = @Col3Value OR @Col3Value IS NULL)
.....
```

Then you can pass actual (chosen) value or DBNull.Value for non-chosen columns.